# Samba shares don't work when mounted via host names from /etc/hosts

Tags: linux, ip, samba, cifs, hosts

I have `/etc/hosts` file with this line

```
10.1.17.123 SAMBAWINSERVER
```

I am trying to mount `samba` shares referencing server by name in the `hosts` file. I tried to mount it via regular `mount` command or `/etc/fstab` as a `cifs` share. I also it via `smbnetfs` which relies on `fuse`. The result is identical in both cases. It refuses to mount shares by `SAMBAWINSERVER` (it runs Server 2012) but works perfectly well when I replace it with `10.1.17.123`. Ping by name works.

I also have a `DROBO` file server mapped as

```
10.1.17.124 SAMBADROBOSERVER
```

When I mount shares from `SAMBADROBOSERVER` server by name it works fine whichever way I mount. `DROBO` internally is a linux machine and I am guessing this may make a difference. My speculation is that `windows` server doesn't like to be called anything but what it calls itself. But why would windows even care about what I call it in my local `hosts` file?

At this point I need help from other experts. Is there something I can do on either `linux` machine or `windows` server in order to be able to rely on `/etc/hosts` entries when mounting `samba` shares?

Comment: Do you have the nmbd running?

Comment: Windows server naturally can't run nmdb. Client linux machine doesn't run nmdb server. I am not sure the client needs it since it successfully mounts samba shares from DROBO.

Comment: Right. How about you set up your /etc/lmhosts file on the client Linux machine?

Comment: Just played a bit with lmhosts. It didn't make a difference. The more I spend time with it the more I get convinced this must be the Microsoft server that plays the joker role here.